# Sharepoint Date and difference

Tags: sharepoint

In my list i have created calculated field to get the difference between the last modified date and today's date.

I use the formula

=datedif([modified],[today],"d")

It is throwing an error : The formula contains reference(s) to field(s).

Please advise.

I do not have a separate column to hold today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Regretfully, you cannot use [Today] for calculated fields. Calculated fields only update when an item is modified, so the [Today Trick](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/) of creating a column named Today, setting your calculated field, then deleting that column, is a bad move.

You have a couple options, the best of which is probably to use JavaScript within a Content Editor Web Part on the page to do the calculation for you. You could also try using SharePoint designer and custom XPath and xslt to get "days since modified" to appear on your page.

Generally, if you want something to identify items that haven't been modified in a while, it should be done with filter library views: they *can* use [Today], and they don't require tricks or workarounds.